# What is the meaning of "slope of ca"?

Tags: calculus, plane-curves, curves

I'm reading a paper, when this article refers to the function:

$$\beta(v)=\frac{(\frac{v}{I})^k}{1+(\frac{v}{I})^k}$$

It say that "around the $I$, $\beta$ is approximately linear in $I$, and has a slope of **ca.**   $\bar{\beta}=\frac{k}{4I^k}$ ".

What is the meaning of this phrase? What is the meaning of **ca**?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps "circa" = approximately...?

Comment: It's an abbreviation of the Latin word *circa*, meaning approximately. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circa

Comment: Thank you very much to you both!